# Задача про Диету Деда Мороза C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Задача про Диету Деда Мороза, подробнее на картинке. Самая простая задача из тех что были, все решил эту не удается. Помогите с решением пожалуйста.
(C++17)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream inp;
    ofstream otp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    otp.open("output.txt");
    double K = 0, P = 0, Q = 0, N = 0, cpd = 0, ans = 0;
    inp >> K >> P >> Q >> N;
    cpd = (Q - P) / (K - 1);
    otp << fixed << setprecision(5) << (cpd * N);
    return 1;
}
```

https://codeshare.io/5wKVnD

[image: Zadacha]

Comment: Что именно у Вас не получается? Можете привести конкретный код?

Comment: Вот код что я написал за несколько минут :

Comment: Какое-то кривое усдовие. По-видимому подразумевается, что коэффициент пропорциональности постоянен и неизвестен. Собственно, задача тогда и заключается в его нахождении.

Comment: добавьте код в вопрос, в комментарии его читать невозможно

Comment: Можно пожалуйста код в вопрос, там есть кнопка специального форматирования кода :)

Comment: Добавил, @LazyTechwork

Comment: _Вот код что я написал за несколько минут_ - а если чуть напрячься и почитать гугл и потратить не пару минут а пару часов на решение? Или вы ждёте что за вас решат?

Comment: @Nilsan Нет, я хотел понять увидят ли люди в моем решении проблемы ибо я их не вижу, и не могу понять почему код не работает.(Выдает не те результаты что должен)

Comment: ..Т.е. это задача на формулу сложного процента.

Comment: @Nilsan Ну и не до конца понимаю абзац в условии про прямую пропорциональность, поэтому и обратился на форум.

Comment: Вам стоит просто назвать переменные своими именами. Подсказка: Вот что такое `cpd`? сколько веса сбрасывалось за 1 день. А что тогда дает `cpd * N`? А вывести надо вес в N-й день

Comment: @VTT по плану cpd * N должно было выдавать ответ на задачу(вес деда мороза на N день диеты)(cpd - сколько веса сбрасывалось за 1 день, вы правы.)

Comment: Если `cpd` - вес сброшенный за 1 день, то `cpd * N` - это вес сброшенный за `N` дней, а не вес Деда Мороза в `N` день.

Comment: @VTT верно. Как мне нужно переделать код чтобы получить вес деда мороза в N день?

Comment: Все равно не понимаю как переделать чтобы было правильно. Извините за мою глупость. Можете подсказать? И если все так просто зачем в условии абзац про пропорциональность? Чтобы запутать?

Comment: @AnT посмотрите комментарии под вашим ответом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Все таки мне кажется ваш ответ не правильный. Либо я делаю что-то не так. вот мой код, он явно выдает не те результаты : https://codeshare.io/G8ON7E

Comment: На каком сайте задачи решаешь?

Comment: @VerNick Живу в Украине, Харьков. У нас есть специальный сайт для проведения олимпиад(Я собственно в 9 классе сейчас.)Вот на нем и решаю, сейчас препод закидывает задачи , а когда будет олимпиада(у меня 9 декабря) буду на той-же платформе решать 4 задачи(разной сложности) за 3 часа.
https://dots.org.ua/
Конкретно я решаю тут : https://qbit.dots.org.ua/
Но без логина и пароля зайти туда нельзя.

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko Понятно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это задача на [формулу сложного процента](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B). Вес Деда Мороза в день `i` (при нумерации дней с нуля) равен

```
W = B * (1 + k)^i
```

где `B` - начальный вес, а `k` - коэффициент пропорциональности, а `^` - операция 
возведения в степень.

Чтобы решить задачу, вам нужно использовать веса Деда Мороза в первый день и в последний день, чтобы найти неизвестный коэффициент пропорциональности `k`

```
k = (E/B)^(1/N) - 1
```

где `E` - конечный вес Деда Мороза, а `N` - количество дней в диете. При этом не забывайте, что в задаче нумерация дней идет с 1, то есть `N` равно количеству дней из файла минус 1 (`N = K - 1`).

Получив коэффициент `k` вы по первой формуле сможете найти `W` в любой день диеты.

Для приведенного примера (при условии, что входные данные идут в порядке "конечный вес" - "начальный вес"), значение `k` будет равно `-0.5`.

Разумеется, в формулах можно сделать замену переменной `1 + k` на `m` и избавиться от этого прибавления/вычитания `1`. Но я хотел сохранить соответствие классическому написанию формулы сложного процента.

Comment: Спасибо, ещё не изучал сложных процентов, из-за этого и не смог решить.

Comment: Финальный код получился такой, но судя по всему я сделал где-то ошибку. Обнаружить не смог. https://codeshare.io/5znVEO Тесты ругаются

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko: Прочитайте мое "Внимание!" в ответе.

Comment: Прочитал, сейчас проверю.

Comment: Вы были правы, в условии ошибка! Исправил код, тесты прошли. Вот код, если вам интересно(просто поменял порядок ввода переменных) https://codeshare.io/G8ON7E

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko: Нет, я написал ерунду во своем "Внимание". Ответ `200` является правильным и для пары `100->400` и для пары `400->100`. А вот надо ли вам менять местами ввод - не знаю. Приведенный пример - непоказателен. Вы видимо еще какие-то тестировали?

Comment: Вы может и написали ерунду, но после того как я поменял порядок ввода программа прошла все тесты))

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko: Так я и говорю, чтобы понять, есть ли в условии ошибка, нужны дополнительные тесты.  Пример в условии непоказателен - по нему не понятно, перепутаны пределы или нет. Если у вас сейчас прошли тесты, то значит скорее всего в условии действительно ошибка.